# Collectors.groupingBy giving java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I want to group by a multiple fields of a collection
[image]

based on entityname, jurisdiction, source group the values and stored in a list
I am expecting out put like
[A PACIFIC TRADING POST & LOGO SHOPPE,United States,Hawaii Business Express]=[Alternative_names:A PACIFIC TRADING POST & LOGO SHOPPE (& DESIGN OF OCEAN WITHSUN, SAILBOAT, CLOUDS, 2 ISLANDS, BANNER OVER A CIRCULAR BAND, 2 PALM TREES, 2 FLOWERS AT BASE OF ONE TREE), Identifiers.Other_company_id_number:25510 G5, Identifiers.Name:A PACIFIC TRADING POST & LOGO SHOPPE, status:Inv. Cancelled, Address.Full_address:140 N KALAHEO AVE STE BKAILUA, Hawaii 96734, UNITED STATES, Address.country:United States]

```
Map<List<String>, List<String>> map = Files.lines(Path.of(file)).skip(1).map(s -> s.split(":"))
    .limit(10).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(arr -> Arrays.asList(arr[0], arr[2]),
        Collectors.mapping(arr -> arr[1], Collectors.toList())));
System.out.println(map);
```

and i am getting

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 1



Map<List<String>, List<String>> map5 = Files.lines(Path.of(file), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
    .skip(1).map(s -> s.split(",")).filter(arr -> arr.length > 1).collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(arr -> Arrays.asList(arr[0], arr.length > 2 ? arr[3] : "EMPTY"),
            Collectors.mapping(strings -> String.join(":", strings),
                Collectors.toList())));

System.out.println("map values are : " + map5);
```

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: We can't help you without it.

Comment: Please provide the data that is producing this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect exactly 3 elements after splitting by `':'`, you may want to use `filter` before collecting:

```java
Map<List<String>, List<String>> map = Files
    .lines(Path.of(file))
    .skip(1)
    .map(s -> s.split(":"))    
    .limit(10)
    .filter(arr -> arr.length > 2) // make sure array has at least 3 elements 
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            arr -> Arrays.asList(arr[0], arr[2]),
            Collectors.mapping(arr -> arr[1], Collectors.toList())
        )
    );
```

Or you may want to handle arrays of 2 elements and use some placeholder instead of `arr[2]`:

```java
Map<List<String>, List<String>> map = Files
    .lines(Path.of(file))
    .skip(1)
    .map(s -> s.split(":"))    
    .limit(10)
    .filter(arr -> arr.length > 1) // make sure array has at least 2 elements 
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            arr -> Arrays.asList(arr[0], arr.length > 2 ? arr[2] : "EMPTY"), // use placeholder
            Collectors.mapping(arr -> arr[1], Collectors.toList())
        )
    );
```

Comment: Map<Object, List<Object>> map5 =
        Files.lines(Path.of(file), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1).skip(1).map(s -> s.split(","))
            .filter(arr -> arr.length > 1) // make sure array has at least 2 elements
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                arr -> Arrays.asList(arr[0], arr.length > 2 ? arr[3] : "EMPTY"), // use placeholder
                Collectors.mapping(arr -> Arrays.asList(arr[1], arr.length > 3 ? arr[4] : "EMPTY"),
                    Collectors.toList())));
but still java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4

Comment: In Java array indexes start from 0, so when you refer `arr[4]`, the `arr.length` is 5

Comment: Can i use arr.length > 4 ? arr[4] : "EMPTY"

Comment: sure, it's a correct condition which is true when `arr.length` is 5 or greater, thus, the array has an element at index 4